# How to by pass authentication(microsoft authenticator) while login into the website through selenium script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation, page-objects

After passing login id and password, user must add code from mobile app - microsoft authenticator.
I want to bypass this code pop-up as I'm generating regression suite and it's not feasible to add code every time manually.
Please suggest how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I understand the need to bypass 2FA authentication methods during automated testing. However, it's important to note that bypassing authentication can not be possible unless the service provider provides a sandbox/testing environment.

That being said, if you're testing in a controlled environment and have the necessary permissions, here are a few approaches you can try to bypass the Microsoft Authenticator code pop-up:

1. Disable Two-Factor Authentication (TFA) temporarily in your test environment for the specific user account you are using for testing. This will enable user to login without requiring the authentication code.
2. Create a separate test account specifically for your automated tests, and configure it without two-factor authentication. This way, you can use the test account to log in without encountering the code pop-up.
3. If disabling TFA is not an option, you can work with your development team to introduce a test-specific authentication bypass that allows you to skip the code pop-up during testing. This can be achieved by adding conditional logic in the authentication flow that detects the testing environment and bypasses the code prompt.
4. You can also ask the developers to disable/remove the TFA part form the test environment. this will enable you to login only with the login id and password without requiring and authentication code from the authenticator.

Answer (score -1):

Use this url to resolve microsoft authentication

https://blog.knoldus.com/ways-to-handle-log-in-pop-up-in-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).